# SourceMeter plugin for SonarQube 4.4 errors due to analyse.xml issue. Has anyone been able to resolve this?

Tags: sonarqube

I am evaluating SourceMeter plugin for SonarQube using SonarQube 4.4  and the plugin i downloaded from the SourceMeter website https://www.sourcemeter.com/download/. While i try to execute the code review for a Java project, it always gives me an error in the following line of the analyze.xml.

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\CI\SourceMeter-Java-6.0-x64-windows\analyze.xml:479: exec returned: 255
ERROR: Caused by: exec returned: 255

Line number 479 is as follows.

Could you please help me understand what could be the probable cause of this issue?

Comment: Thanks for trying our plugin. Unfortunately we haven't support the SQ 4.4 yet. First you should try out with SQ 4.3.2. But this looks independent from it. Probably the command line tool has some errors. You should check out the log directory in your result directory that you set up.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same (?) in this environment:

- Windows 7
- Maven built project
- SonarQube

The problem seems to arise from Windows not treating quotes any special yielding problems when trying to start a java process:
`"C:\dev\maven\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\javax.persistence\2.1.0\javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.` (meaning something like syntax error)

This is raised in some `executeJANScript.bat` containing the lines
`set JOPTIONS="-j:|-cp ".;C:\dev\maven\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\javax.persistence\2.1.0\javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar;C:\...""` where the outer quotes should be omitted.

Comment: what is the version of your SonarQube and SourceMeter?